# finding the equation of a graph with 2 given characteristics

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, transformation

I need to find the equation for the graph of $y = x^2$ with the following characteristics
1. congruent to $4x^2 + 8$
2. shares the same translations as $\frac{1}{3x - 9}$

I have attempted this question and the answer I got was $4(\frac{1}{3}(x-3))^2$

I'd like to verify my answer and know where Im wrong if it is incorrect, please.

Comment: It is not clear what "shares the same translations as" means. In any case, your answer cannot be right, because the graph of $f(x)=4\big(\frac{1}{3}(x-3)\big)^2$ is not congruent to the graph of $g(x)=4x^2+8$, at least if "congruent" means "equivalent by a rigid motion." The former parabola is far "fatter" than the latter.

Comment: What does "shares the same translations as $\frac{1}{3x-9}$ mean?